# String input to get a object

Tags: java

i need to retrive info form a private object but im stuck at this.. its keep say there is a 
constructor error

```
public class Screen{
private movie movieObject;


private Screen(movie movieObject){
this.movieObject = movieObject;
}

private ArrayList<movie> movie = new ArrayList<movie>
public void add(){
String title = keyboard.readString("Enter movie title > ");
String name = keyboard.readString("Enter theatre name > ");

movie add = new movie(title,name) // there is error in this part
```

Comment: Adding the definition of the `movie` class wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Also the error you are getting.

Comment: can we see the movie class please?

Comment: You should always, _always_, ***ALWAYS*** name your classes something starting with an uppercase letter. e.g. `Screen` not `screen` and `Movie` not `movie`.

Comment: if you want a reference of type Movie, do `Movie movie`not `movie movie`or `movie movieObject`. Please read some guides...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe: Line 9 above...

```
new ArrayList<movie>();
```

Also if you use standard naming conventions for classes would help us and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your last line is quite strange to me. Try instead:

```
movie.add(new movie(title,name));
```

Also maybe the movie list instanciation should be done in the constructor ?

Comment: `movie` is not a list, it is a class!

Comment: @paul.cioroianu  it is a list AND a class it would appear. because of teh naming issue.

Comment: @Caleryn it sees it as a class... the way he coded also suggests he wants an object created and referenced, not added to a list.

Comment: wow, yo are right, such a confusion because of the names. Maybe the compillor did the same error as I did ? Try rename movie class into Movie (conventionnal class name style).

Answer (score 1):

Your letter casing is wrong

```
movie add = new movie(..)
```

Your class is `Movie` with capital `M`, not `movie`. You should be getting error all over the place, not just the above line

Also, you're missing the `();` here `new ArrayList<movie>();`

And a `;` here `movie add = new movie(..)`.  <--

But that still doesn't take away from the problems with the letter casing.

---

It does look like you want something more like this

```
 ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();

 public void add(){
     String title = keyboard.readString("Enter movie title > ");
     String name = keyboard.readString("Enter theatre name > ");

     movies.add(new Movie(title, name));
 }
```

---

Or maybe you should do something more like this, where your method add a movie, and doesn't concern itself with getting input from keyboard

```
 public void addMovie(Movie movie) {
     movies.add(movie);
 }
```

Then in your `main` you can do something like this

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     Screen screen = new Screen();

     System.out.println("Enter a title");
     String title = keyboard.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Enter a name:);
     String name = keyboard.nextLine();

     screen.addMovie(new Movie(title, name));
 }
```

The last examples make a lot more sense than the way you are trying to do it.